# Symfony 1.4 image not showing from upload directory

Tags: php, html, symfony-1.4

I used symfony 1.4 to make a basic form that contains an image upload widget, (which uploads the image just fine) but when I try to echo the image later on it doesn't show.
This is the code I use to (try to) output my image:

```
    <img src="<?php echo sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'\\'.$post->getImagename() ?>" />
```

A quick peek at firebug shows me that firefox "failed to load given url". but if I copy & paste the url into the address bar it loads the image just fine.

(Please note, I am developing on a windows environment and my project directory contains no spaces.)

Can anyone explain to me why this happens or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `sf_upload_dir` key because it returns the full path to the image inside the webserver. Like: `c:\website\project\web\uploads`.

You should use `sf_upload_dir_name` instead, which returns the path to the uploads folder **inside** the web folder.

Try:

```
<img src="/<?php echo sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir_name').'/'.$post->getImagename() ?>" />
```

Comment: This unfortunately only gives me "//0ed28a4c510eec.jpg" for my image path. I'm starting to think I might have a configuration issue?

Comment: Hum that's strange. You can use directly `/uploads/` then.